# Como recuperar los datos de un campeonato en otra pagina cuando pulso el enlace del card para ver los datalles JS yFIrestore

Tags: javascript, html, base-de-datos, firebase

Buenas tengo una duda a ver si me podéis ayudar estoy intentado recuperar los datos de una colección de firestore en otra pagina cuando pulso el enlace del card. Ahora mismo no me sale nada al pulsar el enlace del card, en la barra de navegación si que me sale el id del campeonato que he seleccionado. Lo que tengo ahora mismo es esto:

misEventos.js guardo los datos en firestore y los recupero en un card con sus datos esto lo hace perfectamente

```
//Recuperar los eventos
// Obtén el contenedor donde se mostrarán los cards
const contenedor = document.getElementById('listaEventos');

// Obtén los datos de la colección
const obtenerDatos = async () => {

  // Obtén el ID del usuario actual
  //const userId = await getUserId();


  const equiposRef = collection(db, "Campeonato");
  const q = query(equiposRef);
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

  querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
    // Acceder a los campos de cada documento
    // Obtén el ID del usuario actual
    const userId = await getUserId();

    // Verificar si el campo "organizador" existe y coincide con el ID del usuario actual
    if (doc.data().usuario === userId) {
    const id = doc.id; // Obtén el ID del documento de Firestore
    const nombre = doc.data().nombre;
    const numCarreras =  doc.data().numCarreras;
    const juego =  doc.data().juego;
    const plataforma =  doc.data().plataforma;
    const fechaInicio =  doc.data().fechaInicio;
    const fechaFin =  doc.data().fechaFin;
    const imagen =  doc.data().imagen;

      // Llamar a la función para generar el card de Bootstrap
      generarCard(id,nombre, numCarreras, juego, plataforma, fechaInicio, fechaFin, imagen);
    }

  });

};

function generarCard(id, nombre, numCarreras, juego, plataforma, fechaInicio, fechaFin, imagen){
  // Crear el HTML del card de Bootstrap
  const cardHTML = `
      <div class="card me-3 w-25 bg-light" data-id="${id}">
        <img src="${imagen}" class="card-img text-center h-50 w-100" alt="Logo del equipo">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="campeonato-info.html?id=${id}" class="enlaceCircuito"><span class="fw-bold">${nombre}</span></a></h5>
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush ">
          <li class="list-group-item bg-light"><span class="fw-bold">Id: </span>${id}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item bg-light"><span class="fw-bold">Nº Carreras: </span>${numCarreras}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item bg-light"><span class="fw-bold">Juego: </span>${juego}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item bg-light"><span class="fw-bold">Plataforma: </span>${plataforma}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item bg-light"><span class="fw-bold">Fecha Inicio: </span>${fechaInicio}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item bg-light"><span class="fw-bold">Fecha Fin: </span>${fechaFin}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;

  // Agregar el card al contenedor utilizando innerHTML
  contenedor.innerHTML += cardHTML;
}

// Invocar la función para obtener y mostrar los datos
obtenerDatos();
```

En el campeonato-info.html

```
 <header class="container-fluid p-5 header-campeonato-detalle mt-5 w-100">
        <div class="row mt-5" id="datosCampeonatoDetalle">
            <h1 id="nCampeonato"></h1>
            <h5 id="juego-Plataforma" class="text-white mb-5"></h5>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav mt-1">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link enlace" href="campeonato-info.html">Info</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link enlace" href="campeonato-races.html">Carreras</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link enlace" href="#">Clasificacion</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <hr class="bg-white">
    </header>

    <main class="container mb-5">

        <section class="container d-flex mt-3">
            <div class="card col-7 me-3 mt-1" >
                <img id="imgCampeonatoInfo" src="" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body" id="descripcionNormativa">
                    <p class="card-text"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
```

por ultimo campeonato-info.js

```
// Obtener el ID del campeonato desde la URL
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const campeonatoId = urlParams.get('id');

// Elementos HTML
const nombreCampeonatoElemento = document.getElementById('nCampeonato');
const juegoPlataformaElemento = document.getElementById('juego-Plataforma');
const imgCampeonatoElemento = document.getElementById('imgCampeonatoInfo');
const descripcionNormativaElemento = document.getElementById('descripcionNormativa');

// Obtener y mostrar los datos del campeonato
const obtenerDatosCampeonato = async () => {
  try {
    const campeonatoDoc = await db.collection('Campeonato').doc(campeonatoId).get();

    if (campeonatoDoc.exists) {
      const campeonatoData = campeonatoDoc.data();

      const nombreCampeonato = campeonatoData.nombre;
      const juegoPlataforma = `${campeonatoData.juego} - ${campeonatoData.plataforma}`;
      const imagenCampeonato = campeonatoData.imagen;
      const descripcionNormativa = campeonatoData.descripcionNormativa;

      nombreCampeonatoElemento.textContent = nombreCampeonato;
      juegoPlataformaElemento.textContent = juegoPlataforma;
      imgCampeonatoElemento.innerHTML = `
        <img src="${imagenCampeonato}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body" id="descripcionNormativa">
          <p class="card-text">${descripcionNormativa}</p>
        </div>
      `;
    } else {
      console.log('El campeonato no existe');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error al obtener los datos del campeonato', error);
  }
};

// Invocar la función para obtener y mostrar los datos del campeonato
obtenerDatosCampeonato();
```